# Is it okay to use shared preferences for big data objects?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know there are some topics and posts about this question, but i want to have an individual feedback.
So in my app i use one shared preferences (file) and gson to store a list of objects, containing big amount of data. So my shared preference file is about 5 MB big and contains ca 1 Mio characters. I know this sounds not really good, but my app works perfectly. No long loading or saving times.

I choose this method, because i ONLY want to store the data, when my app will be closed and between app starts.

I know really good, that shared prefs is not a good way and actually meant for saving small strings for preferences.
So do i have to change this method or is it "okay"? Or does someone know a good solution, which is easy to use and understand, because for me sqlite is difficult and hard to use. Or is there a easy way to store an object into sql? (Maybe a library or a method??)

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: primarily opinion-based ... "okay" can means anything ... from "working" to "best practices"

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your fast feedback!! I agree to you all. Thanky you also for your posted links. I will think about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule of thumb: As long as it works does not necessarily mean it's good. Said that, SQLite is a perfectly valid solution for android applications. There is also a handy [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) on how to save data with SQLite, but the recommended approach is actually to use the [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not meant for big data objects. For that for example you can use SQLite internal database

Answer (score 1):

for temporary bases it is good for store a data in shared preference. If you want to store a big data then you have to use SqLite to store your data in your device.